# SQL Server singular/plural search

Tags: sql-server, e-commerce

How can I return singular form when a user enters the plural form of a noun. eg. On my website product search if a user enters "Gucci low cut pants" the results should return "Gucci low cut pant". I am unable to use Full Text Search as this column is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is still full-text search. I believe you misunderstand the limitations. A unique index is required on the table (surely you have one of those); it does *not* have to be on the column(s) that you're interested in including in your full-text index. I'm not even sure how that would possibly work, since a unique index can't have a key size > 900 bytes, and full-text search certainly works on columns that can't be declared unique (e.g. max types)...

Comment: thank you I have never used this feature before, I got the free-text search set up now I just need to figure out how to use it for singular/plural searches, I don't need the other features.

Comment: Have you ever figure out this to have singular/plural search?